# How to access value in data-attributein an x-editable context?

Tags: jquery, x-editable

This code triggers the display of a form with multiple fields (a postal address), for inline editing. I want to get the values (`street_name`, and more ) from data attributes in the triggering element. The code below doesn't do this. If I put a string "Broadway" then it does display. It IS possible to do this in `params` (see code).

The documentation contains an example of a form with multiple fields but the values are hardcoded.

Using `$(this).editable().attr('steet_name')` also doesn't work in `value` (`undefined is not a function`)

How can get the values I need from the data attributes of the triggering element?

EDIT - I'm using this JS for several different triggering elements, so I can't just set up a `var street_name = $("#letterAddress").data('street_name');`

```
$('.editable-address').editable({
        url: '/en/ajax/methods?method=normalize-address',
        mode:'inline',
        // Here $(this).attr() doesn't work
        value : {
            street_name: $(this).attr('data-street')
        },
        // Here, $(this).attr() does work
        params: function(params) {
            params.column = $(this).attr('data-column');
            return params;
        }
    });
```

EDIT adding relevant HTML

```
<a
            id="letterAddress"
            href="#"
            class="editable-address editable-empty-address"
            data-column="ind_id"
            data-street_name="<?=$addresses[1]->street_name?>"
            data-street_nbr="<?=$addresses[1]->street_nbr?>"
            data-city="<?=$addresses[1]->city?>"
            data-zipcode="<?=$addresses[1]->zipcode?>"
            data-country="<?=$addresses[1]->country?>"
            >
                <?=$address?>
            </a>
```

EDIT: found my own **solution**. By wrapping the `editable()` code around a `click` event I can assign the data attribute values of the clicked element to variables which are then available to be used in the `editable()` code. Note the `editable('show')` at the end

```
$('.editable-address').click(function() {

        var street = $(this).attr('data-street_name')

        $(this).editable({
            url: '/ajax/url',
            mode:'inline',
            value:  {
                adr_street_name: street
            },
            params: function(params) {                    
                return params;
            }
        }).editable('show');

    })
```

Comment: *Welcome to StackOverflow!* Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Fair enough but the question is less clear now ...

Comment: sry, wasn't finished yet! ... :/

Comment: Can you include your (relevant) HTML markup?

Comment: Added relevant HTML markup

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to access the "data-street" property of the following tag, use the `data` function:

```
<a href="#" data-street="some street" data-zip-code="12345">
<script>
    var value = $(this).data('street');
    var zip = $(this).data('zip-code');
</script>
```

Edit: For new markup

```
var col = $(this).data('column');
var street_name = $(this).data('street_name');
var street_nbr = $(this).data('street_nbr');
var city = $(this).data('city');
var zipcode = $(this).data('zipcode');
var country = $(this).data('country');
```

Comment: Can not - I'm using the JS for several different triggering elements. Updated my question. And I don't think your $(this) refers to the <a> tag, unless you stick it in an onclick() ?

Comment: What happens if you don't specify `value`? It should gather it from the element's `text()`.

Comment: I think you're right but this is a form with several fields (street, nbr, zip, city) you have to specify which values go where

Comment: You'll have to do it programatically, I think. Unfortunately, I don't have access to a test environment right now. Try using `console.log` to  display the values, and see what exactly you have available.

Answer (score 0):

Those will be pulled into the data attribute.

```
$(".editable-address").each(function(){
    var data = $(this).data();
    console.log(data);
});
```

returns the object for each editable address

```
{column: "ind_id", street_name: "<?=$addresses[1]->street_name?>", street_nbr: "<?=$addresses[1]->street_nbr?>", city: "<?=$addresses[1]->city?>", zipcode: "<?=$addresses[1]->zipcode?>"}
```

You could then iterate through the object to get what ever values you needed.

Comment: Nice idea but I'm using this code for several addresses on the page $('#letterAddress').data() is only good for one address

Comment: uh.  ok so just make it generic for your editable classes and use the "this" keyword to access the data for that specific object .

Answer (score 0):

Now you can have JSON object in the data-value attribute:

```
<a href="#" data-type="address" data-value="{city: 'Moscow', street: 'Lenina'}">Link</a>
```